# Graphing functions ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, graph, math-functions

I am looking for a **graphing library** that can be used to graph **functions**, not data points. I have searched for a graphing library that:

1. **graphs mathematical functions**, rather than data points (both is fine as long as it does the first)
2. is **ReactJS-compatible**

and have had poor luck finding a library with both. Is anyone aware of one?

Thanks!!